# List and accessing a method

Tags: java

Assuming I have everything imported (Desktop is an abstract class implementing Product, and Macintosh and Windows are concrete classes that extend Desktop (all lacking a compareTo method), what is a potential work-around to why am I receiving an error that the compareTo() and getYear() methods are not found. I am not sure how to go about fixing this error, and please don't provide a complicated explanation since I am still learning java; just guide me towards the solution.

**I am getting the errors of: cannot find symbol - method compareTo(product) and cannot find symbol - method getYear()**

I have tried various things such as changing Comparable-Product to Comparable-Car, but that does not work. I have also tried casting, but that didn't fix the problem. Also, I want the compareTo method only in the Car class, not in any of the other classes. 
The situation is that Product is an interface, with Car and the abstract method Desktop implementing them. Desktop has two concrete methods Macintosh and Windows extending it. Car is supposed to have the implementation of Comparable interface. The main method is in its own class named Client.

```
interface Product
{
  String getName();
  double getCost();
}

public class Car implements Product, Comparable<Product>
{
    private String name;
    private double cost;
    private int year;
    public Car(String name, double cost, int year)
    {
      this.name = name;
      this.cost = cost;
      this.year = year;
    }
    public String getName() {return name; }
    public double getCost() {return cost; }
    public int getYear() {return year;}
    public int compareTo(Product p)
    {
        if (getCost() < p.getCost())
              return -1;
        else if (getCost() == p.getCost())
              return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
//Client class with java.util.* imported. 
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Product> inventory = new ArrayList<Product>();
    inventory.add(new Windows("Surface Book Pro", 1200, 32));
    inventory.add(new Windows("Surface Book Pro", 1700, 64));
    inventory.add(new Macintosh("MacBook Pro", 1300, "a1278"));
    inventory.add(new Macintosh("MacBook Pro", 1500, "a1502"));
    inventory.add(new Car("Lamborghini Huracan", 200000, 2018));
    inventory.add(new Car("Lamborghini Aventador", 399500.0, 2016));
    int first = -1;
    int second = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++)
    {
      if (!(inventory.get(i) instanceof Car))
        continue;
      if (first == -1)
      {
        first = i;
        continue;
      }
      if (second == -1)
      {
        second = i;
        int year1 = inventory.get(first).getYear();//**Error Here**
        int year2 = inventory.get(second).getYear();//**Error Here**
        String name1 = inventory.get(first).getName();
        String name2 = inventory.get(second).getName();
        int comparison = inventory.get(first).compareTo(inventory.get(second));//**Error Here**
        if (comparison < 0)
          System.out.println("The " + year1 + " " + name1 + " is less expensive than the " + year2 + " " + name2);
        else if (comparison == 0)
          System.out.println("The " + year1 + " " + name1 + " is as expensive than the " + year2 + " " + name2);
        else
          System.out.println("The " + year1 + " " + name1 + " is more expensive than the " + year2 + " " + name2);
        first = second;
        second = -1;
      } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you did to resolve this by yourself. Also, please elaborate on your exact problem you cannot solve. Then, we could give you a rod...

Comment: To clarify, this is all of my own code, and I am not sure what to go about changing. The exact problem is that I am receiving an error, and I am not sure how to fix the error (error mentioned above). I have tried changing Compareable<Product> to Compareable<Car> but that worsens the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is about the `Product` not having the methods. And you will only have `Car`'s in your loop to work with. Why not `cast` your `Product`'s to `Car`'s and use them as such? Try it and let me know if it works.

```
[...] 
if (second == -1) { 

    second = i; 
    Car c1 = (Car) inventory.get(first) ;
    Car c2 = (Car) inventory.get(second) ;
    int year1 = c1.getYear(); 
    int year2 = c2.getYear() ;
    String name1 = c1.getName(); 
    String name2 = c2.getName(); 
    int comparison = c1.compareTo(c2);

    if (comparison < 0) 
           System.out.println("The " + year1 + " " + name1 + " is less expensive than the " + year2 + " " + name2); 
    else if (comparison == 0)            
            System.out.println("The " + year1 + " " + name1 + " is as expensive than the " + year2 + " " + name2); 
    else 
            System.out.println("The " + year1 + " " + name1 + " is more expensive than the " + year2 + " " + name2);
     first = second; 
     second = -1; 
    }
 }
 [...]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had tried Casting earlier, but I forgot parenthesis in my code, so that is why it did not work.

Comment: Did you try to add a 3rd, 4th car to the collection?

Answer (score 0):

```
int year1 = inventory.get(first).getYear();
```

Inventory is a List of Products, so inventory.get (x) will return a Product, but Product has no method .getYear();

The analog is true for compareTo. The compiler can't verify, that this will be an comparable entry.

Create collections by type, and probably a merged one, which you need elsewhere:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Product> inventory = new ArrayList<Product>();
        List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        List<Desktop> desktops = new ArrayList<Desktop>();

        desktops.add(new Windows ("Surface Book Pro", 1200, 32));
        desktops.add(new Windows ("Surface Book Pro", 1700, 64));
        desktops.add(new Macintosh ("MacBook Pro", 1300, "a1278"));
        desktops.add(new Macintosh ("MacBook Pro", 1500, "a1502"));
        cars.add (new Car ("Lamborghini Huracan", 200000, 2018));
        cars.add (new Car ("Lamborghini Aventador", 399500.0, 2016));

        for(Car car : cars)
        {
            inventory.add (car);
        }
        for (Desktop desktop : desktops)
        {
            inventory.add (desktop);
        }

        for(Car car1 : cars)
        {
            for (Car car2 : cars)
            {
                if (car1 != car2) {
                    int comparison = car1.compareTo (car2);
                    String cmp = "as";
                    if (comparison < 0)
                        cmp = "less";
                    else if (comparison > 0) 
                        cmp = "more";
                    System.out.println("The " + car1.getYear() + " " + car1.getName() + " is " + cmp + " expensive than the " + car2.getYear() + " " + car2.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to avoid, to compare car1 with car2, and later car2 with car1, you can copy the cars to a second collection, and remove every first-compared car from the second list. You then don't need to compare if you have the identic car:

```
    List<Car> cars2 = new ArrayList <> ();
    for(Car car : cars)
    {
        cars2.add (car);
    }
    for (Car car1 : cars)
    {
        cars2.remove (car1);        // new 

        for (Car car2 : cars2)
        {
            int comparison = car1.compareTo (car2);
            String cmp = "as";
            if (comparison < 0)
                cmp = "less";
            else if (comparison > 0) 
                cmp = "more";
            System.out.println("The " + car1.getYear() + " " + car1.getName() + " is " + cmp + " expensive than the " + car2.getYear() + " " + car2.getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand that, but my assignment says: Create second product class (Car) that will implement the Product interface and Comparable<T>. I have done that. I am unsure on how to go about the solution so that I am able to receive no error. In other words, how would you go about fixing the error, since you have only identified the issue.

Comment: This is a viable solution, and thanks, however a much elegant solution that I had tried earlier without parenthesis is:
        int year1 = ((Car)inventory.get(first)).getYear();
        int year2 = ((Car)inventory.get(second)).getYear();
        String name1 = inventory.get(first).getName();
        String name2 = inventory.get(second).getName();
        int comparison = ((Car)inventory.get(first)).compareTo(inventory.get(second));

Comment: It's not more elegant. If your check fails, you will end up casting Desktops to Cars. Or try to add a 3rd Car to your collection.  Casting and asInstanceOf, instanceof are code smells.